# Renorming to another Euclidean space to decrease the operator norm of a given operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Recall that the *operator norm* of $B$ is defined by
$$ \|B\| = \max_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Bx\|,$$
where the norm denotes the standard Euclidean norm.

Now imagine we put another *Euclidean* norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ \|x\|_M = \sqrt{\langle x,Mx\rangle}, $$
where $M$ is (symmetric and) positive definite.
This norm will give rise to a corresponding $M$-operator norm:
$$ \|B\|_M = \max_{\|x\|_M\leq 1}\|Bx\|_M.$$

My *question* is this: How small can we make $\|B\|_M$, treating $M$ as a variable?
I checked my Linear Algebra texts (Horn-Johnson, Meyer, etc.) but nothing springs to mind. A lower bound appears to be the spectral radius $\rho(B)$. *Motivation:* In some cases, one could hope for $\|B\|_M<1$ and then one deals with a Banach contraction and thus gets convergence of iterates. So how small can $\|B\|_M$ get, and how to find the matrix $M$ that does the job? (Interesting counterparts are making it large, or moving to a general Hilbert space, by the way.)

Any reference to a book or paper would be greatly appreciated. I suspect that this is already well known, but I cannot find it in my books.

Comment: Manipulation of the $M$-norm definition gives me $\|B\|_M = \|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}\|_2$. This says that the norm is unchanged if $B$ and $M$ are simulaneously diagonalizable. I think you can assume $M$ is diagonal by multiplying on both sides with its unitary diagonalizing transformation. You may be able to use something like this to characterize the largest singular value https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304318/change-in-singular-values-of-matrix-after-left-multiply-with-a-diagonal-matrix

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks! Here $M$ is free, it only has to be positive definite. Would that allow me to lower the quantity?

Comment: I'm not sure. One thing that is readily apparent is that $\rho(B) \leq \|B\|_M \leq \|B\|_2$ from the formula I wrote and submultiplicativity. However, $\rho(B) = \|B\|_2$ for normal matrices, so any improvement can only occur on non-normal matrices $B$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for this comment. However, I am not interest in the general linear group, just the positive definite matrices. Would you know of a result for this set?

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks! It seems unlikely that $\|B\|_M$ is always $\leq \|B\|_2$?

Comment: @user1551 That would be cool. Can you please formally answer the question and leave a reference for this result? Thanks.

Comment: My apologies, there should be a factor of $\lambda_{1}/\lambda_{n}$ in front of the 2-norm, where these are the eigenvalues of $M$ in decreasing order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\|x\|_M=\|M^{1/2}x\|_2$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|B\|_M
&=\max_{\|x\|_M\le1}\|Bx\|_M\\
&=\max_{\|M^{1/2}x\|_2\le1}\|M^{1/2}Bx\|_2\\
&=\max_{\|v\|_2\le1}\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}v\|_2\\
&=\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}\|_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
When $M$ is allowed to be complex Hermitian, it is well-known that
$$
\inf_{M\succ0}\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}\|_2=\rho(B).
$$
This result is often used to prove that the spectral radius is the infimum of all submultiplicative matrix norms.

With slight modification, the proof of this result can be adopted to the case where $M$ is required to be (real) symmetric positive definite.

For any $M\succ0$, let $x$ be a (possibly complex) unit eigenvector corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue of $M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}$ over $\mathbb C$. Then
$$
\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}\|_2\ge\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}x\|_2=\|\rho(M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2})x\|_2=\rho(B).
$$
It remains to show that there exists a sequence of positive definite matrices $\{M_t\}_{t\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\|M_t^{1/2}BM_t^{-1/2}\|_2\to\rho(B)$ as $i\to\infty$. Since the spectral norm is orthogonally invariant, we may assume without loss of generality that $B$ is in block-Schur form, i.e., we assume that $B$ is block-upper triangular, its diagonal sub-blocks are either $2\times2$ or $1\times1$ and these sub-blocks are in the form of
$$
B_1,\ldots,B_r,\lambda_{r+1},\ldots,\lambda_{r+(n-2r)},
$$
where each $B_k$ is of the form $\pmatrix{a_k&-b_k\\ b_k&a_k}$ with $b_k\ne0$ (so that each conjugate pair of complex numbers $a_k\pm ib_k$ are non-real eigenvalues of $B$) and each $\lambda_k$ is a real eigenvalue of $B$. Now, for each $t\in\mathbb N$, let
$$
M_t=\operatorname{diag}(I_2,\,tI_2,\,t^2I_2,\,\ldots,t^{r-1}I_2,\ t^r,\,t^{r+1},\ldots,t^{r+(n-2r)-1}).
$$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\|M_t^{1/2}BM_t^{-1/2}\|_2
&=\|\lim_{t\to\infty}M_t^{1/2}BM_t^{-1/2}\|_2\\
&=\|\operatorname{diag}(B_1,\ldots,B_r,\lambda_{r+1},\ldots,\lambda_{r+(n-2r)})\|_2\\
&=\rho(B).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Can this be made constructive? Given a concrete $B$, what is the best $M$, or at least an $\epsilon$-best $M$?

Comment: @max_zorn There isn't a best $M$ in general, as the set of all positive definite matrices is not compact. E.g. when $B$ is nilpotent but nonzero, there does not exist an $M$ such that $\|M^{1/2}BM^{-1/2}\|_2=0=\rho(B)$. For an $\epsilon$-best $M$, it suffices to pick $t$ such that $\frac{1}{t}\|C\|_2<\epsilon$, where $C$ is the off-block-diagonal part of the block-Schur form of $B$.